# jquery confirm text use function

Tags: jquery, text, confirm

I'm using jQuery confirm, I want to this function:
after click the button,the jQuery confirm text value should be some value with the selected datatables and here is my code

```
    $("#bt-del").confirm({
        text:"Are you sure to delete" + getSelectedTable().length + "rooms?",
        confirm: function(button){ do something },
        ......
```

and **getSelectedTable()** code:

```
    function getSelectedTable(){
    var selected = new Array();
    table.rows('.selected').data().toArray().forEach(function(info,i){
        selected.push(info.roomid);
    });
    return selected;
};
```

but when i click the **bt-del**, it doesn't work,i mean the **getSelectedTable**  function is not executed.

Comment: can you add a fiddle for this?

Comment: I am sorry, it takes long time to add fiddle, the problem i met is jQuery.confirm.js it's **text** option can't use a external function

Comment: @page, try out [jquery-confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm) instead it supports the callbacks that you're looking for.